# Using ReactiveX and SignalR in WebApi

Tags: c#, signalr, reactivex

I am trying to integrate ReactiveX and SingalR with WebApi following: http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/SignalR-and-Reactive-Extensions-are-an-Rx-for-server-push-notifications. I have got the service running using WebApi template, but I am not able to capture any data on the client side

Here is my code:

```
public class ObservableFaceID
{
    public ObservableFaceID()
    {
        var rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        var Generator = Observable.Generate<double, UserModel>(
            initialState: 0,
            condition: (val) => true,
            iterate: (val) => rand.NextDouble(),
            resultSelector: (val) => new UserModel
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Image = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello world"))
            },
            timeSelector: (val) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(val));

        Generator.Subscribe((value) =>
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ObservableFaceIdHub>();
            context.Clients.All.Broadcast(value);
        });
    }
}
```

**ObservableFaceIdHub**

```
public class ObservableFaceIdHub : Hub
{
}
```

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    faceID = new ObservableFaceID();
}
```

by depbugging the service, I can see that the service is working fine and I can see that it keeps generating a new data
but the Client (console application) is not capturing any data.:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cn = new HubConnection("http://localhost:44302/");
    var sensor = cn.CreateHubProxy("ObservableFaceIdHub");

    sensor.On<UserModel>("Broadcast", (item) => Console.WriteLine(item.ID));
    sub = sensor.Subscribe("Broadcast");
    sub.Received += Sub_Received;
    cn.Start().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Sub_Received(IList<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> obj)
{

}
```

Did I miss something?
I can point out that the only changes between my code and the referred code is in this line:

this is my line:

```
context.Clients.All.Broadcast(value)
```

the reference line:

```
context.Clients.Broadcast(value)
```

Comment: `sub = sensor.Subscribe("Broadcast");sub.Received += Sub_Received` are also a deviation.  did you try running this without those, or commented out?

Comment: @BrettCaswell yes, I only added these two lines later trying to find a way to get things working

Comment: *Note here that the casing of the proxy is important and uses Camel casing even though the implementation on the server used Pascal casing* .. from your link.. I'm thinking you should change `ObservableFaceIdHub` to `observableFaceIdHub`.. I'll see if I can find documentation on it and give an appropriate answer

Comment: @BrettCaswell thanks. I have tried with Camel casing. still cannot get any data

Comment: Is there any other way to test the data being generated? I have debugged the app and both Method resultSelector & Generate.Subscribe keep getting called. Is it the correct behavior?